# How to pass query params in form-data in rails link_to instead of appending it in url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page which displays the transaction search results and i have a search filter based on one column(Token) upon clicking this the search criteria should be set and the search params should be passed as a form-data in post method. but currently, it is getting appended to the URL. Kindly, help me[image: Search results]

[image: search based on token]

_payment_transaction.html.erb

```
    <div class="block">

  <% if @transactions_exceed_limit %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="block-title" id="max-fetch-results-message">
        <h4 class="text-primary">Your search returned too many results, so only the first <%=
          TransactionSearchController::MAX_FETCH_SIZE %> results have been displayed.</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="row" style="width:100% !important;">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="block-title">
        <% if @integratedApi == false %>
          <h3><strong> <%= @transactions.count %> results found</strong></h3>
          <%else %>
        <h3><strong> <%= @total_records %> results found</strong></h3>
          <%end %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="csvButton">
        <%= form_tag(csv_path(params.except('controller', 'action').merge(format: "csv")), method: "post") do %>
          <%= submit_tag "Download CSV", class: 'btn btn--charcoal-ghost', id: 'download_csv' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
    <hr class="line">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive tb-responsive tble-responsive">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="search-result-table" style="margin-left:2%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Transaction Id</th>
          <th>Order Id</th>
          <th>Store Id</th>
          <th>Transaction Date</th>
          <th>Transaction Type</th>
          <th>Tender Type</th>
          <th>Token</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Currency</th>
          <th>Response </br>Code</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% if @integratedApi %>

          <% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= link_to transaction[:paymentTransactionId], details_path(:id=> transaction), {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></td>
              <td><%= transaction[:paymentSessionId]%></td>
              <td><%= transaction[:storeId]%></td>
              <td><%= transaction[:createTimestamp].in_time_zone(@timezone).strftime('%B %d, %Y - %l:%M %p') %></td>
              <td><%= @transaction_types[transaction[:transactionType]] %></td>
              <td><%= @tenders[transaction[:tenderType]][1] %></td>
              <td><%= link_to transaction[:paymentAcctUniqueId], params.merge(account_id: transaction[:paymentAcctUniqueId], show_results: "true",clickAccount:"Y"), id: "act_id" %></td>
              <td><%= PaymentsHelper.amount_with_currency_symbol transaction[:transactionAmount], transaction[:isoCurrencyCode]%></td>
              <td><%= transaction[:isoCurrencyCode]%></td>
              <td><%=transaction[:responseCode]%></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>


          <% else %>
          <% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>

            <tr>
              <td><%= link_to transaction['payment_transaction_id'], details_path(payment_transaction_id: transaction['payment_transaction_id']), {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></td>
              <td><%= transaction['payment_session_id'] %></td>
              <td><%= transaction['store_id'] %></td>
              <td><%= transaction['create_timestamp'].in_time_zone(@timezone).strftime('%B %d, %Y - %l:%M %p') %></td>
              <td><%= @transaction_types[transaction['transaction_type']] %></td>
              <td><%= @tenders[transaction['tender_type']][1] %></td>
              <% if (@tenders[transaction['tender_type']][0]).in?(['PLCC', 'GC', 'CC', 'CBCC']) %>
                <td><%= link_to transaction['payment_acct_unique_id'], params.merge(account_id: transaction['payment_acct_unique_id'], show_results: "true",clickAccount:"Y"), id: "act_id" %></td>
              <% else %>
                <td><%= transaction['payment_acct_unique_id'] %></td>
              <% end %>
              <% if show_settlement_type? %>
                <td><%= PaymentsHelper.settlement_amount_with_currency_symbol transaction['transaction_amount'], transaction['iso_currency_code'],transaction['settlement_type'] %></td>
              <% else %>
                <td><%= PaymentsHelper.amount_with_currency_symbol transaction['transaction_amount'], transaction['iso_currency_code'] %></td>
              <% end %>
              <td><%= transaction['iso_currency_code'] %></td>
              <% if transaction['transaction_status'] == ('F') %>
                <td>Payment Service Error</td>
              <% else %>
                <td><%= transaction['response_code'] %></td>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
          </tr>
        <% end %>


        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="modal-window" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
</div>
```

Search.html.erb

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    pt_default_time_gap = <%= ENV['PAYPTL_TRANSACTION_SEARCH_DEFAULT_TIME_GAP_IN_DAYS']%>;
    pt_max_time_gap = <%= ENV['PAYPTL_TRANSACTION_SEARCH_MAX_TIME_GAP_IN_DAYS']%>;
    pt_max_from_date_time_gap = <%= ENV['PAYPTL_TRANSACTION_SEARCH_MAX_TIME_GAP_FROM_CURRENT_DATE_IN_DAYS']%>;
</script>
<% provide(:title, 'Transaction Search') %>
<div id="load"></div>
<% content_for :sub_header do %>
  <%= form_tag({controller: "transaction_search", action: "search"}, method: "post", style: "margin-bottom: 20px;", id: "search_crit_form") do %>
    <%= render "search_criteria" %>

    <div class="row" id="advanced_filters" style="display:none;">
      <%= render "transaction_search/advance_filters" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<div id="contents">
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-top: 15px" id="search_results">

  <div class="search_results_pane" id="search_results_table">
    <% if @transactions.present? %>
      <%= render partial: "transaction_search/payment_transaction", object: @transactions %>
    <% else %>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block-title" id="emptyResults">
          <h2 class="text-primary"><strong>No Results </strong> Found</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

transaction_search_controller.rb

```
   require 'base64'
require 'rest-client'
require 'xmlrpc'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'date'
require 'will_paginate/array'

class TransactionSearchController < ApplicationController
  include PaymentsHelper
  include ApplicationHelper
  protect_from_forgery except: :details
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :can_view_payments_txns?
  before_action :set_store_and_timezone
  before_action :tenders_and_transaction_types, only: [:search, :details]
  before_action :settlement_status, only: [:details]

  DEFAULT_TIME_GAP_IN_DAYS = "#{ENV['PAYPTL_TRANSACTION_SEARCH_DEFAULT_TIME_GAP_IN_DAYS']}".to_i.freeze
  DATE_FORMAT = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'.freeze
  SHOW_MOCK_TRANSACTION = ("#{ENV['PAYPTL_TRANSACTION_SEARCH_EXCLUDE_MOCK_TXS']}" == "true").freeze
  PAYMENTS_URI = "#{ENV['PAYPTL_PAYMENT_SERVICE_PROTECT_PAN_URI']}".freeze
  PAYMENTS_USERNAME = "#{ENV['PAYPTL_PAYMENT_SERVICE_PROTECT_PAN_USERNAME']}".freeze
  PAYMENTS_PASSWORD = "#{ENV['PAYPTL_PAYMENT_SERVICE_PROTECT_PAN_PASSWORD']}".freeze
  MAX_FETCH_SIZE = "#{ENV['PAYPTL_TRANSACTION_MAX_FETCH_SIZE']}".to_i.freeze
  MAX_FETCH_SIZE_CSV = "#{ENV['PAYPTL_TRANSACTION_MAX_FETCH_SIZE_CSV']}".to_i.freeze
  TRANSACTION_SEARCH_REST_API_ENABLED_FLAG = "#{ENV['PAYPTL_TRANSACTION_SEARCH_REST_API_ENABLED_FLAG']}"
  PTF_CLIENT_MANAGEMENT_SERVICE_URL = "#{ENV['PAYPTL_PTF_CLIENT_MANAGEMENT_SERVICE_URL']}"

  def search
    @integratedApi=false
    if TRANSACTION_SEARCH_REST_API_ENABLED_FLAG == 'Y'

      @integratedApi=true
      payload = Hash.new
      if params[:per_page].present?
        @selected_per_page = params[:per_page]
      else
        @selected_per_page = 2000
      end
      params[:page] = params[:page] || 1
      payload['storeIds'] = params[:store_ids]

      params[:start_date] = params[:start_date] || Time.now.utc.to_date.days_ago(DEFAULT_TIME_GAP_IN_DAYS - 1).beginning_of_day.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
      params[:end_date] = params[:end_date] || Time.now.utc.to_date.end_of_day.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
      payload['startDate'] = params[:start_date]
      payload['endDate'] = params[:end_date]
      payload['pageNum'] = params[:page]
      payload['perPage'] = @selected_per_page
      payload['paymentSessionId'] = params[:payment_session_id] if params[:payment_session_id].present?
      payload['paymentAcctUniqueId'] = params[:account_id] if params[:account_id].present?
      payload['transactionTypes'] = params[:transaction_types] if params[:transaction_types].present?
      payload['tenderTypes'] = params[:tender_types] if params[:tender_types].present?
      payload['transactionStatuses'] = params[:transaction_statuses] if params[:transaction_statuses].present?
      payload['isoCurrencyCode'] = params[:iso_currency_code] if params[:iso_currency_code].present?
      payload['transactionAmount'] = params[:transaction_amount] if params[:transaction_amount].present?
      @transaction_search_results = get_transaction_search_details(PTF_CLIENT_MANAGEMENT_SERVICE_URL + "/payments/transaction/search", payload)
      if @transaction_search_results.present? && @transaction_search_results.kind_of?(Hash) && @transaction_search_results.has_key?(:transactions)
        @total_records = @transaction_search_results[:totalCount]
        @total_records = @total_records.nil? ? 0 : @total_records.to_i
      @transactions = @transaction_search_results[:transactions]
      end
    else
    if @store_list.empty?
      flash.now[:danger] = 'No Store Mapped'
    end


    params[:per_page] = params[:per_page] || 20
    params[:page] = params[:page] || 1
    params[:start_date] = params[:start_date] || Time.now.utc.to_date.days_ago(DEFAULT_TIME_GAP_IN_DAYS - 1).beginning_of_day.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    params[:end_date] = params[:end_date] || Time.now.utc.to_date.end_of_day.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    results
    end
  end

  def get_transaction_search_details(rest_url, payload)
    begin
      rest_resource = RestClient::Resource.new(rest_url,ENV['PAYPTL_PTF_CLIENT_MANAGEMENT_SERVICE_USER_NAME'], ENV['PAYPTL_PTF_CLIENT_MANAGEMENT_SERVICE_PASSWORD'])
      Rails.logger.debug("Calling Transaction Search URL:#{rest_url}\n Payload:#{payload.to_json}")
      @transaction_search_response = rest_resource.post payload.to_json, :content_type => 'application/json'
       if @transaction_search_response.code == Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE[:ok]
        return JSON.parse(@transaction_search_response, :symbolize_names => true)
      else
        Rails.logger.error("Transaction search return status code #{@transaction_search_response.code} for payload #{payload}")
      end
    rescue => e
      Rails.logger.error(e.message)
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Unable to fetch data, Please try later'
    end
  end

  def results
    start_date = Time.strptime(params[:start_date], DATE_FORMAT).utc.beginning_of_day
    end_date = Time.strptime(params[:end_date], DATE_FORMAT).utc.end_of_day

    condition = Hash.new
    @accountId=params[:account_id]
    condition[:store_id] = @store_for_service
    condition[:payment_session_id] = params[:payment_session_id] if params[:payment_session_id].present?
    condition[:transaction_test_ind] = [0, nil] if !SHOW_MOCK_TRANSACTION
    condition[:transaction_type] = params[:transaction_types] if params[:transaction_types].present?
    condition[:transaction_amount] = params[:transaction_amount] if params[:transaction_amount].present?
    condition[:iso_currency_code] = params[:iso_currency_code] if params[:iso_currency_code].present?
    condition[:tender_type] = params[:tender_types] if params[:tender_types].present?
    condition[:transaction_status] = params[:transaction_statuses] if params[:transaction_statuses].present?
    @page=params[:page]
    if(@accountId!=nil && @accountId!='')
      condition[:payment_acct_unique_id] = @accountId
      if(params[:clickAccount]=='Y')
        @page=1
        params[:clickAccount]='N'
      end
    end
    condition[:transaction_status] = params[:transaction_statuses] if params[:transaction_statuses].present?
    if params[:action] == 'csvexport'
      @transactions_export_csv = PaymentTransactionFlat.where(:create_timestamp => start_date..end_date).where(condition).order(create_timestamp: :desc).limit(MAX_FETCH_SIZE_CSV)
    else
      @transactions = PaymentTransactionFlat.where(:create_timestamp => start_date..end_date).where(condition).order(create_timestamp: :desc).limit(MAX_FETCH_SIZE + 1)
      if @transactions.present?
        @transactions = @transactions.to_a
        if @transactions.count > MAX_FETCH_SIZE
          @transactions = @transactions[0..(MAX_FETCH_SIZE - 1)]
          @transactions_exceed_limit = true
        end

=begin
        @transactions = @transactions.paginate(:per_page => params[:per_page], :page => @page, :total_entries => @transactions.count)
=end
      end
    end
  end

  def details
    @integratedApi=false
    if TRANSACTION_SEARCH_REST_API_ENABLED_FLAG == 'Y'
      @integratedApi=true
    @transaction = params[:id]
      else
    @transaction = PaymentTransactionFlat.transaction_details(params[:payment_transaction_id])
    if @transaction.present?
      @settlement = PaymentTransactionFlat.settlement_transaction(@transaction['payment_transaction_id']).first
      @response_cc_auth = PaymentTransactionFlat.response_cc_auth(@transaction['payment_transaction_id']).first
      if @settlement.present?
        @auth_transaction = PaymentTransactionFlat.authorization_transaction(@settlement['auth_pmt_transaction_id']).first
        @customer_billing_address = PaymentTransactionFlat.customer_billing_address(@settlement['auth_pmt_transaction_id']).first
        @settlement_history = PaymentTransactionFlat.settlement_transaction_history(@settlement['payment_transaction_id'])
      end
    end
    end

  end

  def retrieve_payload(account_number, tender_class)
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml.ProtectPanRequest('xmlns' => 'http://api.gsicommerce.com/schema/checkout/1.0') do
        xml.PaymentAccountNumber_ account_number
        xml.TenderClass tender_class
      end
    end

    return builder.to_xml
  end

  def retrieve_account_number(account_number)
    if account_number.present? && account_number =~ /^[0-9]+$/
      rest_client = RestClient::Resource.new(PAYMENTS_URI, PAYMENTS_USERNAME, PAYMENTS_PASSWORD)

      PaymentsHelper::TENDER_CLASS.each do |key, value|
        begin
          response = rest_client.post retrieve_payload(account_number, value), :content_type => 'application/xml'
          parsed_response = Hash.from_xml(response)
          account_number = parsed_response.try(:[], 'ProtectPanReply').try(:[], 'Token') || account_number
          break
        rescue RestClient::RequestFailed
          next
        end
      end
    end
    account_number
  end

  # Code for CSV generation

  # Enable the CSV library
  require 'csv'

  # Action for generating the CSV
  def csvexport
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv do
        send_data export_to_csv(results),
                  filename: 'transactions.csv',
                  type: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present',
                  disposition: 'attachment'
      end
    end
  end

  # Method for generating the csv file
  def export_to_csv(records)
    # Header names used in CSV file
    csv_header = ['Transaction Id', 'Order Id', 'Store Id', 'Transaction Date', 'Transaction Type', 'Tender Type', 'Token', 'Amount', 'Currency', 'Response Code']
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << csv_header
      records.each do |record| # Quick fix for CSV download problem to export only specified columns
        csv << [record['payment_transaction_id'], record['payment_session_id'], record['store_id'], record['create_timestamp'].in_time_zone(@timezone).strftime('%B %d, %Y - %l:%M %p'), record['transaction_type'],
                record['tender_type'], record['payment_acct_unique_id'],
                if record['transaction_amount'].to_s.present?
                  record['settlement_type'].to_s.casecmp("C")== 0 ? '-$' +
                record['transaction_amount'].to_s : '$' + record['transaction_amount'].to_s else ' ' end, record['iso_currency_code'],
                record['response_code'] == ('F') ? 'Payment Service Error' : record['response_code']]
      end
    end
  end

  def get_store_timezone
    render json: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo(get_timezone(@selected_store)), status: :ok
  end

  private

  def set_store_and_timezone
    params[:store_ids] = get_default_store if params[:store_ids].blank?
    @selected_store = params[:store_ids]
    @store_for_service = replace_with_store_mappings(@selected_store, ApplicationHelper::PAYMENTS_SERVICE)
    @timezone = get_timezone @selected_store
    zone_map = JSON.parse((ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo @timezone).to_json)
    @moment_timezone = zone_map['identifier']
  end

  def tenders_and_transaction_types
    @tenders = Rails.cache.fetch(:payment_tenders) {PaymentRecord.tenders}
    @transaction_types = Rails.cache.fetch(:payment_transaction_types) {PaymentRecord.transaction_types}
  end

  def settlement_status
    @settlement_statuses = Rails.cache.fetch(:payment_settlement_statuses) {PaymentRecord.settlement_status}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

A **link_to** will always put the arguments into the query string as it is creating a get-style HTML link - even if you put :method => :post that just appends an extra ("special") argument _method.

What will work according to your requirement is **button_to** helper provided by rails, which will make it into a form-post.

Please follow the link given below for more details:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Comment: I just referred the link and changed to button_to (<%= button_to transaction[:paymentAcctUniqueId], search_path, method: :post, :params => {:account_id => transaction['payment_acct_unique_id']} %>) but how to retain the original params

Comment: One way could be passing the params in the controller and the using it for further request, other way could be storing them in cookie or session and then retrieving it

Comment: I am passing params in button_to like below

Comment: I am passing params in button_to like below.  (<%= button_to transaction['payment_acct_unique_id'], search_path, method: :post, :params => {:account_id => transaction['payment_acct_unique_id'], :show_results => 'true', :clickAccount =>'Y', :store_ids => @selected_store, :start_date => params[:start_date], :end_date => params[:end_date]}, form: { "data-type" => "json" }%>). I need store_ids to be store_ids[]: EGFTUS
store_ids[]: HIBUS. like this. store_ids is multiple select.But passing params in button_to i am getting (store_ids: EGFTUS/HIBUS)

Comment: since you passing @selected_store to store_ids, please check what is being contained in this, also please look into where are all selected values being stored

Comment: its an array of store_ids (["HIBUS", "EGFTUS"])